# Automator - Connect to Server at Startup based on MAC Address

Tags: automator, external-disk, server.app

I've spent half of my day yesterday trying to figure this out, so I thought it may be useful for someone else in the same situation.

I wanted to automatically Connect to a Server at Startup but not based on the IP Address, but based on the MAC address of my device. This was needed because I change routers from time to time and this change gives a new IP Address to my server device.

Comment: The usual solution would be to assign a fixed IP address to the server.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add a short shell script in the Automator application to get the IP address based on the MAC address.

```
ip_address=$(arp -a | grep "YOUR_MAC_ADDRESS" | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1)

url_beginning="afp://"

url_end="/YOUR_USER_NAME"

url="$url_beginning$ip_address$url_end"

echo $url
```

The code above will get the IP address (example: **10.0.0.5**) of the device with the YOUR_MAC_ADDRESS MAC Address (example: **0:10:75:57:13:22**). Then it will concatenate the correct URL (example: **afp://10.0.0.5/YOUR_USER_NAME**) and connect it as shown in the image below.

[image]